# In Excel, formula to format numbers as strings?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-office

I'm helping a coworker clean up a massive excel spreadsheet, and a few of the columns contains a mix of strings and numbers. I want to turn the numbers to text (changing the format to TEXT doesn't resolve it on it's own). Based on what I've been doing, I need to have the little green "error" triangle pop up. I'm not really eager, and neither is anyone else in the world, to double click each cell individually. Is there a way to force the `'` in front of each cell? It needs to use Excel macros/functions as my coworker is not a programmer and I'm not really willing to dedicate the time to script it.

I've tried doing `=("'"&[CELL])` but it just puts the literal `'` in the cell rather than formatting it. Thanks.

Comment: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/10/10/excel-convert-number-text/

Answer (score 1):

This code brings up the little green error triangle.
It's looks very similar to the small snippit of code you gave in that it just adds a `'` onto the front of the cell value, so not sure why your code didn't do that.
**Note** that it will overwrite formula with the result of the formula (preceded by the `'`).

```
Sub Test()

    Dim rCell As Range

    For Each rCell In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A5")
        rCell = "'" & rCell
    Next rCell

End Sub
```

**Edit:**

I gave the VBA code as your post says *"It needs to use Excel macros/functions"*, but your tag is `excel-formula` so maybe you meant the opposite.

Try this formula:
`=TEXT(A1,"0")`
This won't add the triangle, but if you copy and paste values over your original numbers the triangles appear.

Comment: Yeah sorry. I'm not on the up and up with MS office Jargon. but the formula is what I meant. Thanks I'll give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of depends on what exactly is making each cell be formatted as text. Since you mentioned in your comment that you're actually looking for a formula, here's the basic way to convert strings to values:

```
=VALUE(A1)
```

Anything this doesn't work on likely has something else in the cell (i.e.: punctuation, letters, etc.) that makes it so Excel can't automatically figure out what number you mean.

Comment: Sorry...mis-read. You're trying to go from number to text, so @Darren's formula solves it. (`=TEXT(A1,"0")`)

Answer (score 0):

The solution given above is almost correct:

Try this formula:
=TEXT(A1,"0")
This won't add the triangle, but if you copy and paste values over your original numbers the triangles appear.

The only thing that you need to add to this is that when you copy and paste values over your original then you need to paste special (ctrl+alt+v) and select "Values" - then it works!

Comment: Which one do you mean by "given above"?